# How to change NavigationAgent3D pathing

Tags: 3d, godot, path-finding, gdscript, godot4

I'm relatively new to the Godot 4.1 game engine and currently am struggling to understand how can I change (if possible) the way NavigationAgent3D creates its pathing and its coordinates for said pathing. I've read the documentation for NavigationAgent3D but I didn't find the answer to my issue or maybe missed it.

I know it uses A* to create the shortest path to the target position but I want to modify the pathing so it resembles something like this in the image below but in 3D:

[image]

As per the image above, I'm trying to make it so the pathing becomes grid based & the player goes to a set of coordinates.

This is my current scene structure:

**Main (TestLevel1)**

[image]

**Player**

[image]

If any more information is required from my end, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set path_prosessing to edgecenter in the navigation agent.

It is also possible to add navigation to each mesh then enable the bakenavigation in the gridmap.But I think just using edgecenter is enough to get what you are looking for.